# Pass parameters in uibmodal

Tags: angularjs

I would like to ask on how can i get the passed value in my function.
Please see below.

$scope.showupdate=function(id){
$uibmodal.open({
         templateUrl:’location’,
         controller:’controller’
});

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

You are doing little bit wrong. Instead of pass data on `open()` I suggest you to pass name of `component` and it will call that component. You have to just do some RND with your module.